# JS загрузить данный полученные от сервера в таблицу

Tags: javascript, html

В html страничке есть:

```
<table class="table table-hover" id="tablePatient"> 
 <thead>
 <td>Номер</td>
 <td>Открытие</td>
 <td>Закрытие</td>
 </thead>
 <tr>
 <td></td>
 <td></td>
 <td></td>
 </tr>
 </table>
```

c помощью javascript отправляю запрос на сервер к адресу tableDate

```
function f(){
var x = new XMLHttpRequest();
x.open("GET", "tableData", true);
x.send(null);
}
```

От сервера получаю ответ вида:

```
    farex@home:~$ curl -i localhost:3000/listlgotcat
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Date: Sun, 05 Mar 2017 05:58:20 GMT
Content-Length: 6
Content-Type: text/plain; charset=utf-8

№1 Open Close
№2 Close Open
№3 Null Close
farex@home:~$
```

как вывести результат этого запроса в таблицу?

Пытаюсь использовать следующею конструкцию:

```
window.onload = function () {
  var x = new XMLHttpRequest();
    x.onload = function() {
var t = document.getElementById('tablePatient');
    var trs = t.getElementsByTagName("tr");
var tds = null;
    var row = x.responseText.split('\n');
for (var i=0; i < trs.length; i++)
{
tds = trs[i].getElementsByTagName("td");
for (var n=0; n<trs.length;n++)
{
    tds[n].innerHTML = "<div>"+ String(row[n]);+ "</div>"
}
}
};
x.open("GET", "/tableData", true);
x.send();

}
```

Не могу разобраться как ответ сервера в массив перевести.

```
   farex@home:~$ curl -i 176.197.86.74:3000/listNar
   HTTP/1.1 200 OK
   Date: Sun, 12 Mar 2017 08:44:13 GMT
   Content-Length: 30
   Content-Type: text/plain; charset=utf-8
   1 10 Open 
   2 11 Close 
   3 12 Opne
   4 12 Close
   5 13 Close 
   farex@home:~$
```

Comment: x.responseText - в этой переменной будет находиться ваш текст

Comment: про перенос ответа сервера в массив не говорилось.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Обычно отслеживают событие [onreadystatechange](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest/onreadystatechange), оно происходит несколько раз в процессе отсылки и получения ответа. При этом можно посмотреть текущее состояние запроса в свойстве `xhr.readyState`. Так вот, если его (`xhr`) статус ([status](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest/status)) `200 OK`, то берут его ответ ([responseText](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest/responseText)), в котором и находится всё, что нужно.

В общем, теоретически, это выглядит примерно так:

```
xhr = new XMLHttpRequest;
xhr.open('GET', 'tableData', true);
xhr.onreadystatechange = function () {
  if (xhr.readyState == 4) {
    xhr.onreadystatechange = null;

    if (xhr.status == 200) {
      var myvalue = xhr.responseText; // текст ответа.
      console.log(myvalue);
    }
  }
};

xhr.send(null);
```

При получении работаете уже с `myvalue` так, как вам необходимо.

Предположим, что ответ выглядит так:

```
var response = ['№1 Open Close',
                '№2 Close Open',
                '№3 Null Close'
];
```

тогда ответ вставка данных может быть такая:

```js
var response = ['№1 Open Close',
                '№2 Close Open',
                '№3 Null Close'
];

var table = document.getElementById('tablePatient').getElementsByTagName('tbody')[0]; 

response.forEach(function(stringData, index, array){
 var row = table.insertRow(index);  
 var elements = stringData.split(' ');    
  for (var i = 0; i < elements.length; ++i) {
   var cell = row.insertCell(i);
    cell.innerHTML = elements[i];
  }  
});
```

```html
<table class="table table-hover" id="tablePatient"> 
   <thead>
     <td>Номер</td>
     <td>Открытие</td>
     <td>Закрытие</td>
   </thead>
   <tbody><!-- Здесь будет ответ сервера --></tbody>
 </table>
```

---

В целом это может выглядеть так:

```js
function f(){
    xhr = new XMLHttpRequest;
    xhr.open('GET', 'tableData', true);
    xhr.onreadystatechange = function () {
      if (xhr.readyState == 4) {
        xhr.onreadystatechange = null;

        if (xhr.status == 200) {      
          myFunction(xhr.responseText;);
        }
      }
    };

    xhr.send(null);
}


function myFunction(response) {
    var table = document.getElementById('tablePatient').getElementsByTagName('tbody')[0]; 

    response.forEach(function(stringData, index, array){
      var row = table.insertRow(index);  
      var elements = stringData.split(' ');    
      for (var i = 0; i < elements.length; ++i) {
        var cell = row.insertCell(i);
        cell.innerHTML = elements[i];
      }  
    });    
}
```

```html
<table class="table table-hover" id="tablePatient"> 
   <thead>
     <td>Номер</td>
     <td>Открытие</td>
     <td>Закрытие</td>
   </thead>
   <tbody> <!-- Здесь будет ответ сервера --></tbody>
 </table>
```

---

Вообще на ruSO [много вопросов по XMLHttpRequest](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/search?tab=votes&q=new%20XMLHttpRequest). Странно, что вы не нашли подобное там.

Comment: извиняюсь за настойчивость, но как вывести полученные данные в таблицу? (в существующий, или новую)

Comment: @ЕвгенийГусев а в каком формате вы получаете данные? json? Если написать `console.log(myvalue);` то что в консоли будет?

Comment: Не json, просто строки разбитые на "\n" но не проблема переделать в формат json

Comment: ["a1 ", "a2 ", "a3 ", "a4 ", ""]

Comment: @ЕвгенийГусев вообще лучше отдавать массив или json - чтоб проблем по обработке меньше было. Пример с массивом добавил в ответ. В принципе с json будет подобное.......... а если со строкой, разделенной `\n` делать, то `responseText` надо будет в начале поделить на куски, чтоб получить массив  `var myvalue = xhr.responseText; var responseArr = myvalue.split("\n");` и работать как выше описано

Comment: ругается
http://s020.radikal.ru/i721/1703/bc/3e49103435bc.jpg

Comment: @ЕвгенийГусев потому что не массив, как сделать массив написано выше